# LaTeX formulae now look strange

Tags: support, mathjax

A few days ago my internet browser (Google Chrome) was updated and formulae on MSE became strange. I didn't make my own screenshots earlier, but the change you can see below (I've found similar picture):

[image: This was earlier]

[image: How it looks now]

First is from "past", second as it looks now. It seems to me that something is wrong with my MathJaX, but I can't find anything to retrieve previous configuration. How can I deal with this stuff?

(upd)
Here are two screenshots: 1st from Chrome, 2nd from IE. Maybe, this problem reffers not to Chrome only

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, second is a screenshot which I have taken recently (with thin font)

Comment: I misunderstood; Thanks for clarification. Try http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6115 in case the issue is related to DirectWrite feature of Chrome.

Comment: Check if it's not just the zoom options on Chrome.

Comment: @Git Gud, No, in standart zoom everything is the same

Comment: What is your "Math Renderer" setting? (Found in [MathJax context menu](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IeCSf.png)).

Comment: HTML-CSS, as it was earlier

Comment: General observation; don't lose hope or patience. I had to update Linux Ubuntu to get my one-page scanner working, but then my printer would not work, and on and on. Now, when I call up the scanner, I know everything is fine if it says "Failed to create file. Permission denied" or some such, then I close that and it all works.

Comment: What is the operating system? Could be a problem with its fonts.

Comment: Windows 7(x64). Everything was smooth until Chrome update, so I suppose that problem is with browser. As I remember, I had similar problem approx. half year ago, but it vanished by itself, something like @WillJagy said. Sometimes I use 2 computers, so I denied browser update on the second, the version of Chrome is 36.---- there, and the version here is 37.----. But now this problen does not vanish.

Comment: Not something I would know: is it possible to have two different browsers installed and available, then to call up the one that works best with the current website of interest?

Comment: Ok, I will check it on standart IE

Comment: @WillJagy, I've edited my starting post, you can see what's with IE

Comment: Interesting, both quite grainy, like an old dot printer. I do suggest you check on the computers of other people, other internet service providers. Nothing about computers actually makes sense, especially now that so many different people/businesses have some part in the final product, here the appearance of a web page.

Comment: @cool: I marked your question as a duplicate of a newer bug report. If the question is still there can you comment on that one with the current chrome version that you are using? If the question is solved for you can you also comment there about it too? Thanks.

Comment: I was using Chrome 37 at that time, now it is refreshed to 38, and the bug still holds. Moreover, the same I can say about fonts in Wikipedia(ru)